# Photoblogging engine using PHP and MySQL or PostgreSQL

Tags: php, blog, looking-for-a-script, mysql, photo

I am looking for nice looking and with good usability photo blogging software to run on my server. So far I have found PixelPost, Cheesecake and EZPX.
PixelPost - look quite abandoned project
Cheesecake - also quite abadoned
EZPX - Not sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress has documentation dedicated to [photoblogs and galleries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Photoblogs_and_Galleries). Everything you would want to know setting up Wordpress to that is right there.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com/) or [Indexhibit](http://www.indexhibit.org/), with a theme of your choice. Using Wordpress plugins, you can add photo editing functionality.

Comment: @asdf - What plugins you recommend when using WP?

Comment: @Marko Depends on what you want to achieve. Maybe this can help http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/images